# feature duplication on solution redeploy

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I recently had to make a change to one of our custom solutions, but once I redeployed the thing I noticed that the features were duplicated in the features section in site collection administration.

It just appears to be happening with list definitions and content types though.

what gives?

Comment: Did you change the feature ID or package information at all? What version of SharePoint? (2010/2013)

Comment: Hi David. I haven't made any modifications like that, but I've also just recently started this position and don't know exactly what has been done in the past. 

We are using SP 2010.

Comment: Do you have multiple environments you can try this on? On the environment that is affected, go to the 14\TEMPLATES\FEATURES, do you see your feature listed as a folder twice in here? If so, check the feature.xml file, are the feature IDs different?

Comment: There is no duplication in the features folder. It seems that the solution was a copy of of another solution.